# Customizing Wordpress Header and Nav Bar to my own PHP Include

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a php website and and have included a blog within the site utilizing Wordpress blog. I am not very experienced with Wordpress at all, but I am trying to replace the header and nav bar with the one from the site so everything matches. I know that a Wordpress is database driven, but Im sure there has got to be a way to drop in a php include in there somewhere to do this correctly. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Old question but will answer anyway:
The template files you need to modify are in `/yourblogfolder/wp-content/themes/yourtemplatefolder`. Open `header.php` and replace the code between
`<header>` and `</header>` with your header and nav code. Same for `footer.php`.